# Type 'bigint' is not assignable to type 'BigInt'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

[image: So this seems strange to me. I'd expect this from a number, but not from a bigint. Am I missing something about bigint literals? I realize I could solve this problem by just using BigInt(0) or whatever, but if possible I'd like to do something a bit tidier.]

So this seems strange to me. I'm hovering over this error in VSCode, where I am trying to assign a BigInt to 0n. I'd expect this from a number, but not from a bigint. Am I missing something about bigint literals? I realize I could solve this problem by just using BigInt(0) or whatever, but if possible I'd like to do something a bit tidier.

Comment: This should not error. Can you share the code where `Holder` and `stellaHolding` is declared? Is this maybe a modified `BigInt` type?

Comment: stellaHolding: BigInt!

Comment: Yan you ctrl-click on `BigInt` and see in which file you end up?

Comment: I've got the definition in a .graphql schema, and when I try to go to the definition it tells me "no definition found for BigInt".

But, if I invoke BigInt in my code and go to the definition, it takes me to an index.ts file under graph-ts (which is a library I imported). Which makes me think I am in fact using a different BigInt, which would explain this.